# Merge 2 DataFrames so that DataFrame 1 contains a column with the joined values from a column in DataFrame 2

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My source data (simplified, contains more columns in reality):

```
eig_df = pandas.DataFrame({
    'KG-EZ': [50101,50101,50101,50101,50103],
    'EZ': [17,18,19,19,1],
    'Name': ['Name1','Name2','Name3','Name4','Name5']
})
eig_df.set_index(['KG-EZ', 'EZ'], inplace=True)

gst_df = pandas.DataFrame({
    'KG-EZ': [50101,50101,50101,50101,50101,50103,50103],
    'EZ': [17,17,18,19,19,1,1],
    'GST-NR': ['GST1','GST2','GST3','GST4','GST5','GST6','GST7']
})
gst_df.set_index(['KG-EZ', 'EZ'], inplace=True)
```

I have 2 DataFrames, the first represents people, the second represents plots they own.
The data is provided by a municipality, I have no control over it.
`KG-EZ` and `KG` together are the columns for joining, but are not unique in either DataFrame.

I want to merge them so that the first DataFrame (of people) gets an additional column `GST-NR` that contains all matching values from the second DataFrame, comma-separated.
So for the test data, this should be the result:

```
result_df = pandas.DataFrame({
    'KG-EZ': [50101,50101,50101,50101,50103],
    'EZ': [17,18,19,19,1],
    'Name': ['Name1','Name2','Name3','Name4','Name5'],
    'GST-NR': ['GST1,GST2','GST3','GST4,GST5','GST4,GST5','GST6,GST7']
})
result_df.set_index(['KG-EZ', 'EZ'], inplace=True)
```

I have tried `merge()`, but that gives me multiple rows per person, and I tried to generate a new Series using `apply()`, but I can't find the right lambda that will filter the other DataFrame by the current index and give me the comma-separated values.

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) with `Series` created by aggregate `join`:

```
result_df = eig_df.join(gst_df.groupby(['KG-EZ', 'EZ'])['GST-NR'].agg(','.join))
print (result_df)
           Name     GST-NR
KG-EZ EZ                  
50101 17  Name1  GST1,GST2
      18  Name2       GST3
      19  Name3  GST4,GST5
      19  Name4  GST4,GST5
50103 1   Name5  GST6,GST7
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks so much, would have never found that by myself!